# How to add icon and active class for specific ul id?

Tags: jquery

I have two navigation. One have `<ul id="menu-topmenu"></ul>` and second have `<ul id="sidebar-menu"></ul>` I need to find this id="menu-topmenu" but i dont know how? Any suggestion? This is my navigation:

```
<nav>

<div class="menu-topmenu-container">
  <ul id="menu-topmenu" class="menu">
    <li id="whats-on" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-53"><a href="#whatson">What’s On</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-10 current_page_item menu-item-52"><a href="#" class="active">Visiting Us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href=#">Collections &amp; Research</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="#">Learning</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my script:

```
$(function() {
  var href = window.location.href;
  $('nav a').each(function(e,i) {
    if(this.parentNode.id.indexOf('menu-topmenu') != -1){
            $(this).addClass('active');

    }
    else if(href.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) >= 0) {
          $(this).addClass('active').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="margin-left:5px;"></i>');
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parentNode` of clicked anchor is list item, so that code tries to look for the specific `id` on the parent `li` and which is not there. Instead you can use `.closest()` to traverse up in the DOM to look up a specific id.

You have to use `.closest()` to traverse up:

```js
$(function() {
  var href = window.location.href;
  var $link = $('nav a[href*="' + href + '"]');

  $link.toggleClass('active', $link.closest('#menu-topmenu').length !== 0);

  if ($link.closest('#menu-topmenu').length == 0) {
    $link.append('<i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="margin-left:5px;"></i>');
  }
});
```

Comment: @None what is the use case actually? why don't you filter it like `$('nav  #menu-topmenu a')`

Comment: again it adds active class to all li with <ul id="menu-topmenu"> and never add icon to other li without that id

Comment: IMHO you should not use each loop at the doc ready.  instead once again you can check the answer. This will only target to those elements once at page load.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;

$('nav').find('a').each(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).attr('href') == loc);
   $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="margin-left:5px;"></i>');//for adding symbol
});
```

Comment: do i need to change all of my code with this part of your code or?

Comment: give full path to your `href`.

Comment: it add active class but what about icon? where to add that?